# When are the level curves of a polynomial bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$. I want to understand when $f$ has the following property: for all sufficiently large (positive) $k$, the level curves defined by

$$\displaystyle f(x,y) = k$$

consist of a finite number of bounded components. Clearly it is sufficient to assume that $f$ is positive definite, or when the Hessian of $f$ is strictly positive definite for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Is there a relatively simple necessary and sufficient condition for this phenomenon?

Comment: The necessary and sufficient condition is that $|f(x,y)|\to+\infty$ as $x^2+y^2\to +\infty$.

Comment: For a Zariski closed subset $X$ of $\mathbf{R}^2$, the property "$X$ consists of a finite number of bounded components" is equivalent to "$X$ is bounded". So you require that for every $k$ (real? integer?) large enough, $f^{-1}(\{k\})$ is bounded. Or I misunderstand your formulation?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Well, constant maps also satisfy the condition.

Comment: For $n\ge 2$ and a continuous map $f:\mathbf{R}^n\to\mathbf{R}$, it is easy to check that $f^{-1}(\{k\})$ is bounded for all $k$ large enough, if and only if either $f$ is bounded or $|f(x)|\to\infty$ when $\|x\|\to\infty$.

Comment: @YCor: I disagree: for a constant polynomial, one level set is unbounded.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I know, but the question specifies "all sufficiently large (positive) $k$"